# IBM Worklight - unable to run some projects

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Can you tell me why some of my projects don't run in Worklight? I've received a couple of projects from other people, some work, some don't. I've tried this on Worklight 6.0 as well as 5.0.6 but I'm seeing the same errors, see below (this happens when trying to deploy the app to the Worklight server, on my local console):

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: java.lang.RuntimeException: BaseProjectLocal is null
at com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal.get(BaseProjectLocal.java:41)
at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal.get(ProjectLocal.java:55)
at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal.getCoreBeanFactoryS(ProjectLocal.java:95)
at com.worklight.core.util.RssBrokerUtils.getBeanFactory(RssBrokerUtils.java:60)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.getOrCreateAuthenticationContext(AuthenticationContext.java:99)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:119)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: BaseProjectLocal is null
... 9 more
```

I've also tried to create the project manually and paste the common folder over but that's no good either. Any help would be appreciated here.

Further Information: This is importing a project into Eclipse. This was previously a project that was built in Worklight 5.0.6 and is being imported to Worklight 6.0. I am simply right clicking on the common folder > run as > build all and deploy. I then see the following message 'Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: Worklight module MobileWalletSencha was not successfully started. Full details of the error are available from the Worklight Development Server console' and then I see the error log shown above. If I add this content to a new project, yes it fails as well then.

Comment: It would be easier if you could share one of the projects that fail. With an error like "java.lang.RuntimeException: BaseProjectLocal is null" there is nothing much one can say.

Comment: BTW, what and how are you trying to deploy? is this a .war file? a .wlapp file? a project you import to eclipse and try to build? Add more details about the phenomena (anything you can, don't be shy on details). Please edit the question with this information - NOT in comments.

Comment: If you create a new project - it works, but if you add it the contents of a project that fails, it then fails as well? Edit the question with the contents that makes the project fail - it would be best to share this failing project.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you could share one of the projects that fail. With an error like "java.lang.RuntimeException: BaseProjectLocal is null" there is nothing much one can say.

BTW, what and how are you trying to deploy? is this a .war file? a .wlapp file? a project you import to eclipse and try to build? Add more details about the phenomena (anything you can, don't be shy on details). Please edit the question with this information.

Also, if you create a new project - it works, but if you add it the contents of a project that fails, it then fails as well? Edit the question with the contents that makes the project fail - it would be best to share this failing project.